# Difference between await Task and await Func<Task>()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a program which needs to run a number of async tasks in parallel. The main difference between two implements, `Task1()` and `Task2()`:

`Task1()` saves the `FTask` of type `Func<Task>` and later await `Task.WhenAny(FTask())`,

`Task2()` saves the `Task` produced by `Task.Run()` and later await `Task.WhenAny(Task)`.

I think they should be equivalent, but `Task1()` does not work properly, however `Task2()` does work.

The flow of this program is:
If there are available task contexts in the free queue, dequeue one and setup it up with an async task; when async task finished put the context back to the free queue.

The problem is `Task1()` which saves `Func<Task>` does not work, it seems the async task has more than one instances running.

The complete code is:

```
static async Task Task1()
{
    int qd = 4;
    var taskPool = Enumerable.Range(0, qd).Select(n => new TaskCtx()).ToArray();
    Queue<TaskCtx> qFree = new Queue<TaskCtx>(taskPool);
    Random r = new Random();

    long segs = 7, submit = 0;
    int token = 0;
    int ticket = 0;

    Console.WriteLine($"-------- Task1 start --------");
    
    while (submit < segs)
    {
        if (qFree.Count > 0)
        {
            var x = qFree.Dequeue();
            x.Token = token++;
            x.Delay1 = r.Next(10, 20);
            x.Delay2 = r.Next(30, 50);

            x.FTask = async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] start");
                await Task.Delay(x.Delay1);

                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] wait ticket: {ticket}");
                while (ticket != x.Token)
                {
                    await Task.Yield(); // yield and wait other task increases the ticket
                }
                
                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] acquire ticket: {ticket}");
                await Task.Delay(x.Delay2);
                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] release ticket: {ticket}");
                ticket++;
                
                qFree.Enqueue(x);
            };

            Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] submit");
            submit++;
        }
        else await Task.WhenAny(taskPool.Select(x => x.FTask()));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskPool.Select(x => x.FTask()));
    Console.WriteLine($"-------- Task1 finished --------");
}

static async Task Task2()
{
    int qd = 4;
    var taskPool = Enumerable.Range(0, qd).Select(n => new TaskCtx()).ToArray();
    Queue<TaskCtx> qFree = new Queue<TaskCtx>(taskPool);
    Random r = new Random();

    long segs = 7, submit = 0;
    int token = 0;
    int ticket = 0;

    Console.WriteLine($"-------- Task2 start --------");
    
    while (submit < segs)
    {
        if (qFree.Count > 0)
        {
            var x = qFree.Dequeue();
            x.Token = token++;
            x.Delay1 = r.Next(10, 20);
            x.Delay2 = r.Next(30, 50);

            x.Task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] start");
                await Task.Delay(x.Delay1);

                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] wait ticket: {ticket}");
                while (ticket != x.Token)
                {
                    await Task.Yield(); // yield and wait other task increases the ticket
                }
                
                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] acquire ticket: {ticket}");
                await Task.Delay(x.Delay2);
                Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] release ticket: {ticket}");
                ticket++;
                
                qFree.Enqueue(x);
            });

            Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] submit");
            submit++;
        }
        else await Task.WhenAny(taskPool.Select(x => x.Task));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskPool.Select(x => x.Task));
    Console.WriteLine($"-------- Task2 finished --------");
}

public class TaskCtx
{
    public int Token;
    public int Delay1;
    public int Delay2;
    public Func<Task> FTask;
    public Task Task;

    public TaskCtx()
    {
        FTask = async () => await Task.CompletedTask;
        Task = Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The output of `Task1()`:

```
-------- Task1 start --------
[0] submit
[1] submit
[2] submit
[3] submit
[0] start
[1] start
[2] start
[3] start
[0] wait ticket: 0
[0] acquire ticket: 0
[2] wait ticket: 0
[1] wait ticket: 0
[3] wait ticket: 0
[0] release ticket: 0
[1] acquire ticket: 1   <-- [1] is running and got the ticket
[4] submit
[4] start
[1] start               <-- another [1] starts ???
[2] start
[3] start
[2] wait ticket: 1
[1] wait ticket: 1
[1] acquire ticket: 1
[4] wait ticket: 1
[3] wait ticket: 1
[1] release ticket: 1
[2] acquire ticket: 2
[2] acquire ticket: 2
[1] release ticket: 2
[3] acquire ticket: 3
[3] acquire ticket: 3
[5] submit
[6] submit
[4] start
[6] start
[2] start
[3] start
[2] wait ticket: 3
[4] wait ticket: 3
[6] wait ticket: 3
[3] wait ticket: 3
[3] acquire ticket: 3
[2] release ticket: 3
[4] acquire ticket: 4
[2] release ticket: 3
[4] acquire ticket: 4
[3] release ticket: 5
[6] acquire ticket: 6
[3] release ticket: 5
[3] release ticket: 7
[4] release ticket: 8
[4] release ticket: 8
[6] release ticket: 10
```

The output of `Task2()`:

```
-------- Task2 start --------
[0] submit
[1] submit
[2] submit
[3] submit
[0] start
[1] start
[2] start
[3] start
[2] wait ticket: 0
[1] wait ticket: 0
[3] wait ticket: 0
[0] wait ticket: 0
[0] acquire ticket: 0
[0] release ticket: 0
[1] acquire ticket: 1
[4] submit
[4] start
[4] wait ticket: 1
[1] release ticket: 1
[2] acquire ticket: 2
[5] submit
[5] start
[5] wait ticket: 2
[2] release ticket: 2
[3] acquire ticket: 3
[6] start
[6] submit
[6] wait ticket: 3
[3] release ticket: 3
[4] acquire ticket: 4
[4] release ticket: 4
[5] acquire ticket: 5
[5] release ticket: 5
[6] acquire ticket: 6
[6] release ticket: 6
-------- Task2 finished --------
```

UPDATE:
I make another implement, by use a normal async function, not anonymous function:

```
static async Task Task3()
{
    int qd = 4;
    var taskPool = Enumerable.Range(0, qd).Select(n => new TaskCtx()).ToArray();
    Queue<TaskCtx> qFree = new Queue<TaskCtx>(taskPool);
    Random r = new Random();

    long segs = 7, submit = 0;
    int token = 0;
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket(0);

    Console.WriteLine($"-------- Task3 start --------");
    
    while (submit < segs)
    {
        if (qFree.Count > 0)
        {
            var x = qFree.Dequeue();
            x.Token = token++;
            x.Delay1 = r.Next(10, 20);
            x.Delay2 = r.Next(30, 50);

            x.Task = RunTask3Async(x, ticket, qFree);

            Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] submit");
            submit++;
        }
        else await Task.WhenAny(taskPool.Select(x => x.Task));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskPool.Select(x => x.Task));
    Console.WriteLine($"-------- Task3 finished --------");
}

static async Task RunTask3Async(TaskCtx x, Ticket ticket, Queue<TaskCtx> qFree)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] start");
    await Task.Delay(x.Delay1);

    Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] wait ticket: {ticket}");
    while (ticket.ticket != x.Token)
    {
        await Task.Yield(); // yield and wait other task increases the ticket
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] acquire ticket: {ticket}");
    await Task.Delay(x.Delay2);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{x.Token}] release ticket: {ticket}");
    ticket.ticket++;
    
    qFree.Enqueue(x);
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int ticket;

    public Ticket(int t)
    {
        ticket = t;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ticket}";
    }
}
```

`Task3()` also works, the output is:

```
-------- Task3 start --------
[0] start
[0] submit
[1] start
[1] submit
[2] start
[2] submit
[3] start
[3] submit
[0] wait ticket: 0
[3] wait ticket: 0
[0] acquire ticket: 0
[2] wait ticket: 0
[1] wait ticket: 0
[0] release ticket: 0
[1] acquire ticket: 1
[4] start
[4] submit
[4] wait ticket: 1
[1] release ticket: 1
[2] acquire ticket: 2
[5] start
[5] submit
[5] wait ticket: 2
[2] release ticket: 2
[3] acquire ticket: 3
[6] start
[6] submit
[6] wait ticket: 3
[3] release ticket: 3
[4] acquire ticket: 4
[4] release ticket: 4
[5] acquire ticket: 5
[5] release ticket: 5
[6] acquire ticket: 6
[6] release ticket: 6
-------- Task3 finished --------
```

UPDATE2:
I tried to minimal the example but the following code does not have this problem.

```c#
var FTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] start");
    await Task.Delay(i);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] end");
}).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(FTasks.Select(x => x()));

Console.WriteLine("----------------");

var Tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] start");
    await Task.Delay(i);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] end");
})).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(Tasks);
```

Comment: https://www.atmosera.com/blog/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Comment: Ivan your examples are far from minimal. If you want to get a solid understanding of the differences between a materialized `Task` and an asynchronous delegate, you might learn more by making your examples as minimal as possible. A five-ten lines program might be enough to demonstrate the differences.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, I have a minimal one but they don't have this problem. Please see UPDATE2.

Comment: *"the following code does not have this problem"* -- What is the problem that the original complex example has, and the updated minimal example doesn't have?

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias, I updated the description. The flow of this program is: If there are available task contexts in the free queue, dequeue one and setup it up with an async task; when async task finished put the context back to the free queue.

The problem is Task1() which saves Func<Task> does not work, it seems the async task has more than one instances running.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are building a complex mechanism that manages tasks, and the mechanism doesn't work as expected. What is the intended usage of this mechanism? How are you planning to use it in practice? I am asking because before diving into your mechanism in order to figure out what's wrong with it, it might be more productive to see if there are readily available tools that can do the same job. Building such mechanisms from scratch is generally not an easy thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, I'm working on read data from a stream and save to file. The buffer is popped from free queue, starts an async task to read and write, when finished put it back to free queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, the main difference between `Task` and `Func<Task>` is that the first one represents an operation (that has already started), and the second one represents a delegate that starts an operation. This is the same logic as for any `T` and `Func<T>`.

So, the question of "why are these run more than once?" is answered by looking in your `Task1`:

```
        else await Task.WhenAny(taskPool.Select(x => x.FTask()));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskPool.Select(x => x.FTask()));
```

Every time your code calls `FTask()`, it's starting a *new* asynchronous operation. So *each* call to `Task.WhenAny` will start all the tasks in the `taskPool`, and the final call to `Task.WhenAll` will start all the tasks in `taskPool` again.

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem! I have a minimal example to reproduce it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71028077/2823283

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between storing `Task.Run(...)` in a Task and assigning it to a Func is in the timing of excecution. `Task.Run()` starts the work directly whereas the function is lazy, i.e. the work starts when the function is called.

Comment: The output of `Task2()` shows the function is also lazy,  however `Task3()` uses `x.Task = RunTask3Async(x, ticket, qFree);`, and the async function is executed immediately, before the "submit" print.

Answer (score 1):

This question essentially boils down to the difference between calling

```
public Task MyMethod();
```

and calling

```
public void MyMethod()
```

using `Task.Run`. The essential difference is that the second example will explicitly be run on a background thread. The first example will run on the current thread up until the first await. At this point it may continue, or may schedule a 'continuation' at a later time. This continuation will be run on the same synchronization context as the calling thread, this means that in UI programs it will run on the UI thread if called from a UI thread.

For a console program like yours, it will be little practical difference since one of the first operations will be a `Task.Delay`, and since you do not have a UI, it will run the continuation on a thread pool thread.

Comment: But the `Task1()` output show, it looks like more than one instance of task [1] is started, and the function flow is not right.

Comment: @ivan_wl your code do not look thread safe to me. You are incrementing values and reading values without any form of synchronization, and that can cause unexpected behavior in multi threaded programs. I would highly recommend studying thread safe programming before attempting to do anything multi threaded. Since it is very easy to write bugs that are not detected by the compiler, and may be very difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @ JonasH I know thread safe and I don't think this is a thread synchronisation or race condition problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is just like [Stephen says in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71022212/2823283), every time you await a async delegate, a new instance of async task is created and starts from beginning.

This a minimal example to illustrate this problem:

```c#
int i = 0;
var ftask = async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i++}] Func<Task>");
    await Task.Yield();
};

await ftask();
await ftask();

//--------------------

int j = 0;
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{j++}] Task.Run()");
    await Task.Yield();
});

await task;
await task;
```

The output:

```
[0] Func<Task>
[1] Func<Task>
[0] Task.Run()
```